# WebView size always 0

Tags: android, android-webview

I can't seem to get my WebView to display. I suspect it's because its size is 0. I'm not sure how to un-zero this WebView!

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View webViewLayout = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.twitterfeed, null, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView) webViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String summary = "http://www.example.com";
    webView.loadUrl(summary);
    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getWidth());
    System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getHeight());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inflating your layout but never displaying it by attaching it to the app window with `Activity.setContentView()`. Use either

```
View webViewLayout = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
        .inflate(R.layout.twitterfeed, null, false);
setContentView(webViewLayout);
WebView webView = (WebView) webViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

or more simply just let the framework do the inflation for you:

```
setContentView(R.layout.twitterfeed);
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Comment: When I try to setContentView(), I end up with this exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`. This seems strange. Why must I have a ListView?

Comment: You're extending `ListActivity`. Change it to regular `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

- you need to use ViewTreeObserver to measure the webview layout width and height.
- ViewTreeObserver trigers it's global layout listener, and has it's own thread to measure the layout dimensions.

  ```
          webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout()
          {
              System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getWidth());
              System.out.println("webView: " + webView.getHeight());
          }
      });
  ```